# PHP extensions is Disabled when installing Drupal on Local LAMP server

Tags: php, apache, drupal, drupal-7, fedora-25

I'm using **fedora 25** and local **LAMP** server. 
I've Installed all the extensions needed for Drupal, but it says that i need to enable these extensions,

even after I tried this command `php -d extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/xml.so` I found that it's **already loaded** !!! 
how can i enable these extensions for Drupal When it's already enabled ??

[image]

Comment: can you share your `php.ini`? i do forget where that file is located in *nixes.. its around `/etc` i think..

Answer (score 1):

You need to check which `php.ini` is used by `Apache`.

It's typical to have different `php.ini` files: one for the PHP command line (what you tried with your `php -d` command), one for the Apache module, one for the FastCGI style of Apache integration, and so on.

The fact the XML extension is loaded when running the command line PHP executable doesn't mean it's loaded in the other scenarios.

For example, on a Debian distro, there are different conf folders:
`/etc/php5/apache2`, `/etc/php5/cli`, etc. Each of these folders contains a `php.ini`.

This is probably similar on Fedora.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Capsule I've looked for the php.ini file for Apache's main directory and i found this file /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/15-php.conf
is it the file that i should edit it ?

Comment: No, it's a part of the Apache config, it defines how PHP is loaded by Apache. Run the `find /etc/ -name php.ini` command and see what it returns

Comment: it returned to me only one file `/etc/php.ini`

Comment: You can extend the search to the whole server just to make sure there's no other `php.ini` files in exotic locations: `find / -name php.ini`

Comment: Nope the only  `php.ini` file that i found is in /etc/

Comment: Open Reports -> Status report back-end page and next to "php version" click the link "more information". It will open simple php_info page. There, at top of huge page look for "Loaded Configuration File"  - it will give you exact path of loaded php.ini file. php.ini used with web server is different than one used when calling php from console.